# regex match bash variable

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to modify a bash script.  The script current contains

```
print "<div class=\"title\">" $1 "</div>"
```

Where `$1` may look like:

```
Apprentice Historian (Level 1)
Historian (Level 4)
Master Historian (Level 7)
```

What i'd like to do is add an image which is named the "base" value.  I had something like this in mind:

```
print "<div class=\"icon\"><imgsrc=\"icons\" $1 ".png\"></div><div class=\"title\">" $1 "</div>"
```

However, in this case I'd like `$1` to only return `Historian`. I was thinking I could use a regex to match and on `$1` and keep only the part I need.

```
(Apprentice|Master)?\s(.*)\s(\(Level \d\))
```

I know my regex isn't quite there, ideally apprentice/master would be in their own match group and not tied the base.  And I don't know how to match on the `$1` argument.

Comment: [The pony he comes...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/554546)

Comment: Thanks for the link but I'm not actually parsing [x]html.  I'm actually creating an html output based on a few keywords.

Comment: @JackManey I think the OP asks to regex the `Apprentice Historian (Level 1)` kind of string using bash.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using regex matching in bash:

```
for a in 'Apprentice Historian (Level 1)' 'Historian (Level 4)' 'Master Historian (Level 7)' ; do
    set "$a"
    echo " === $1 ==="
    [[ $1 =~ (Apprentice|Master)?' '?(.*)' ('Level' '[0-9]+')' ]] \
        && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[${#BASH_REMATCH[@]}-1]}
done
```

The tricky part is to retrieve the correct member from BASH_REMATCH. Bash does not support non-capturing parentheses, therefore Historian is either under 1 or 2. Fortunately, we know it is the last one.

Answer (score 5):

Samples pure shell:

```
a="Historian (Level 1)"
noParens=${a/ \(*/}
lastWord=${noParens/[A-Za-z]* /}

a="Muster Historian (Level 1)"
noParens=${a/ \(*/}
lastWord=${noParens/[A-Za-z]* /}
```

(It's the same expressions in both cases, just repeated for easy testing).

Answer (score 0):

Based on "And I don't know how to match on the $1 argument."

Have I understood you correctly if what you are asking for is not whether your regex is correct but rather how to perform the match against the contents of your bash variable?

```
matched_text=$(echo $yourbashvariablecontainingthetext | sed 's/your_regex/backreference_etc/')
```

$yourbashvariablecontainingthetext should be your $1